# Bootstrap row attributes not changing in css

Tags: html, css

CSS is awful, and I'm trying to make my life easier by learning how to use bootstrap, but I don't understand why the attributes I'm modifying in my .css file aren't changing the html elements.

In my HTML document I have

```
<div class="container-fluid">

  <div class="row bot">
    <div class="col-lg-4" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-4</div>
    <div class="col-lg-4" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">.col-sm-4</div>
    <div class="col-lg-4" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-4</div>
  </div>


</div>
```

And then in my .css file I have

```
body{
  height: 2000px;
}


.row .bot{
  height: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

But when I refresh my html document the row's background colour doesn't change? In fact it doesn't do anything. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: CSS is not awful. What is it you're trying to do exactly?

Answer (score 1):

change your css to:

```
.row.bot {
  height: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

So remove the space between the two classes.

Comment: Such simple mistakes. Thank you.

Comment: @jm123456 If it was helpful, please accept my answer. Thank you :)

Comment: @jm123456 to expand on Aniko's answer. `.row .bot` is searching for an element with a class of `bot` that is a child of `row` whereas `.row.bot` is searching for an element with both `row` and `bot` classes applied to it.

Answer (score 0):

try this code
  Html code:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row bot">
<div class="cog-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">.col-sm-4</div>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">.col-sm-4</div>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">.col-sm-4</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

css code:

```
body{
height: 2000px;
}
.bot{
/* height: 150px; */
height:100%;
background-color: blue;
}
```

[JS FIDDLE LINK CLICK HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/4jz78eu3/)

PLEASE TRY TO AVOID THE INLINE STYLING AS MUCH AS POSSIBLE.